# VUE 3 Force unmount when deactivated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have VUE app which uses `keep-alive` method in the router. Many pages needs to be loaded only once but some specific pages need to be loaded again each time activated.

```vue
<template>
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive max="5">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>
<template>
```

What I want to do is to `unmount` a page-component from `keep-alive` cache when it is `deactivated`.

```js
/* this is the loaded component */
export default {
  setup() {
    const state=ref({})
    /*init and load data...*/
   
    onDeactivated(()=>{
     //unmount this component ???
    });
    
    return { state };
  },
  components: {},
};
```

What is the best practice you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19) posted an awesome answer but due to a possible bug of VUE (currently I use 3.2.6) it has some issues.

When a component excluded from keep-alive after initiated and then after the max keep-alive components reached, VUE tries to remove the non existent excluded component.

This leads to an error and stalls the app. See below for more about the error.

My solution relies on tony19's mind blowing solution.

Instead of excluding the component after loading it, I added rules to router just before loading the component.

```js
const routes = [
  /* ... */
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "AboutPage",
    meta: { excludeKeepAlive: true },
    component: () => import('./../components/AboutPage.vue'),
  }
  /* ... */
];
```

and then in the main APP;

```js
/* This is the main app */
export default {
  setup() {
    /* ... */
    const keepAliveExcludes = reactive(new Set());

    cont keepAliveExcluder= {
      add: name => keepAliveExcludes.add(name),
      remove: name => keepAliveExcludes.delete(name),
    }
   
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {    
      if(to.meta?.excludeKeepAlive===true){      
        keepAliveExcluder.add(to.name);
      } 
      next();
     });
    /* ... */
   return {
      keepAliveExcludes: computed(() => Array.from(keepAliveExcludes))
    }
   }
}
```

**More about the error (possibly a bug)**

Error occurs in `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2057`

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

VUE cannot find dynamically excluded component.

[image: screenshot of error]

Answer (score 4):

### Conditional `keep-alive`

You could [`provide`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#using-provide) methods for child routes to add/remove themselves to [`keep-alive`'s `exclude` property](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#keep-alive) via a `keepAliveExcludes` reactive set. Expose the ref to the template as a computed **array** (the `exclude` prop requires `Array`, not `Set`):

```js
// App.vue
import { provide, reactive, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const keepAliveExcludes = reactive(new Set())

    provide('keepAliveExcludes', {
      add: name => keepAliveExcludes.add(name),
      remove: name => keepAliveExcludes.delete(name),
    })

    return {
      keepAliveExcludes: computed(() => Array.from(keepAliveExcludes))
    }
  }
}
```

In the app template, bind `keepAliveExcludes` to `<keep-alive>.exclude`:

```html
<template>
  <router-view>
    <keep-alive :exclude="keepAliveExcludes">
      ...
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>
</template>
```

In the child route, [`inject`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#using-inject) the `keepAliveExcludes`, and call its `add`/`remove` with the component's name when needed (e.g., via checkbox):

```html
<template>
  <h1>About</h1>
  <div>
    <label>Keep Alive
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="keepAlive">
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, inject, watchEffect } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'About',
  setup() {
    const { add: addKeepAliveExclude, remove: removeKeepAliveExclude } = inject('keepAliveExcludes', {})

    const keepAlive = ref(true)
   
    watchEffect(() => {
      if (keepAlive.value) {
        removeKeepAliveExclude?.('About')
      } else {
        addKeepAliveExclude?.('About')
      }
    })

    return { keepAlive }
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-keep-alive-conditionally?file=src%2FApp.vue)

### Always exclude from `keep-alive`

If you need to *always* exclude the component from the `keep-alive` cache, you could simply set the component name statically without the complexity of the `provide`/`inject` above.

In the app template, specify the component's name (must match the `name` prop in the component declaration) in `<keep-alive>.exclude`:

```html
<template>
  <router-view>
    <keep-alive exclude="About">
      ...
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-keep-alive-exclude?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Hey. Could you explain why, if I use `const excludes = ref([])` and use it directly (`<keep-alive exclude="excludes">..`), then `unmounted` event does not occur, but when I use the `computed` function as in your example (`keepAliveExcludes: computed(() => Array.from(excludes.value)),`) - then event triggers? I was under the impression that there was supposed to be no difference.. Your solution with `computed` function really helped me in solving the long lasting problem with unmount event not triggering!

Comment: I am just wondering of there are other places in VueJs that require the computed functions instead of reactive components.. Don't want this to hit me later on prod :) Fiddle to repro issue: https://jsfiddle.net/7f2d4c0t/4/ Fix: https://jsfiddle.net/mvj2z3pL/ (turn on console)